How does the router know to send packets to a VM on bridge mode?
How exactly does the router know that, to reach a VM, it needs to reach my computer first? Does VirtualBox alter the local network ARP?
Some people say that you need to set promiscuous mode for bridging to work, so it can capture packets with the MAC address of the VM, but how can you do it with Ethernet if all the traffic goes directly to the destination machine and the VM cannot sniff like on Wi-Fi?

this may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_bridge

I'll try to answer, but from earlier posts, it feels like you're missing some fundamentals necessary to make any sense of the answer... Stop thinking of bridging as something specific to VMs and revisit how an Ethernet switch works – e.g. how the switch that's built in to your router works – as it's exactly the same kind of bridge as your VM host is.


How exactly does the router know that, to reach a VM, it needs to reach my computer first? Does VirtualBox alter the local network ARP?


On Ethernet: The router doesn't need to know. Bridges are transparent – packets are not directed at a bridge's MAC address specifically; they can be directly sent to the target system's MAC address and if there happen to be any bridges in between, it's their job to forward the packets through the correct port.
So when the router first makes an ARP query for the VM's IP address, your host's VirtualBox bridge forwards it unmodified and lets the VM reply with its own MAC address.
This all works exactly the same as if you had an Ethernet switch with multiple devices behind it.

On Wi-Fi: The VirtualBox bridge rewrites all packets so that they appear as if coming from the host's MAC address instead. (That is, it does NAT for MAC addresses.)



Some people say that you need to set promiscuous mode for bridging to work, so it can capture packets with the MAC address of the VM, but how can you do it with Ethernet if all the traffic goes directly to the destination machine and the VM cannot sniff like on Wi-Fi?

Consider what makes traffic go directly to the destination machine in the first place. Bridges work by learning MAC address locations from traffic generated by the machine itself – e.g. when a switch receives a packet from source Y through port 3, it learns that packets for destination Y should likewise be sent through port 3.
So when your VM generates traffic from its own MAC address, all Ethernet bridges along the way will learn its location, and traffic to the VM's MAC address will automatically be directed back through the same path – there is no need to 'sniff' anything because the packets will get delivered directly at the host's Ethernet interface.

Perfect, and thanks you all

By putting the physical NIC in promiscuous mode, the VM is able to receive ARP requests for its IP address, to which it replies with its virtual MAC address. So the router's ARP table contains an entry for the VM's IP address, mapped to the VM's virtual MAC address, just like it would have for an OS running on bare metal on any other computer.
Any intermediate switches will see traffic coming from the VM's virtual MAC address and learn that that MAC address is reachable out that switch port, and update the switch's CAM table (bridge table of which MAC address is out which port) accordingly.
